# initial value for ModelForm field not working

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm tring to set the `user` field as the logged-in user, but it's returning `None`. Here's my model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.TextField(max_length=76)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField(null=False, default='')
    image = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default='1')
```

my form:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=PagedownWidget)
    title = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'title'})

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            'title',
            'content',
            'category',
            'image',
            'id',
            'user'
        ]
```

and my view where users make a post using a form:

```
def post(request):
    allauth_login = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    allauth_signup = SignupForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        data = {'user': request.user}
        form_post = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES, initial=data)
        if form_post.is_valid():
            category = form_post.cleaned_data['category']
            for a, b in CATEGORY_CHOICES:
                if a == category:
                    category = b
                    form_post.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/%s' % category)
        else:
            form_post = PostForm()

        context = {
            'allauth_login': allauth_login,
            'allauth_signup': allauth_signup,
            'form_post': form_post
        }

        return render(request, 'post.html', context)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/accounts/signup/")
```

When I actually render the form in my template, `{{ obj.user }}`returns `None`. Any idea why?

```
{% for obj in Post.objects.all() %}
    {{ obj.title }} #works
    {{ obj.content }} #works

    ...

    {{ obj.user }} #does not work

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I don't see where you're defining `obj`. Did you mean to put `user` in `context`?

Comment: No that's just the template `{% for obj in Post.objects.all() %}`. all the other fields work, e.g. `{{ obj.title }}`, only `user` doesn't work (renders as `None`)

Comment: Are you sure that your posts are actually associated with a user?

Comment: So you mean the `obj` is from DB querying, not the post form? Or you supposed saving post form first and then query it from DB with updated `user` field? Anyway, providing template code would be helpful.

Comment: @user2896976 isn't that the point of my `ForeignKey(User)` field?

Comment: Yes it's from DB querying. In a seperate view which renders the results of the form. There isn't any problem with the template as every field works, except user. So the only problem is that `initial={'user':request.user}` does not work

Comment: @YKLi i've added the template into my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are initializing form incorrectly. If request method is not POST form will contain errors.

Try this:

```
form_post = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, initial=data)
```

**UPDATE**

You can also try to do it this way. Remove user field from form and in view do this:

```
if form_post.is_valid():
    instance = form_post.save(commit=False)
    instance.user = request.user
    instance.save()
```

Comment: @Zorgan add `print(request.user)` to the view to check current user name.

Comment: I just printed it under `if request.user.is_authenticated():` and it prints the correct logged-in username

Answer (score 0):

I think you mixed up with `initial` and `bound form with data`. In your case, I'm guessing you're trying to save post with valid user first, and then redirect to the page to show the new post with user.

So it should be:

```
def post(request):
    allauth_login = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    allauth_signup = SignupForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        data = request.POST.copy()
        data['user'] = request.user
        form_post = PostForm(data, request.FILES)
        if form_post.is_valid():
            category = form_post.cleaned_data['category']
            for a, b in CATEGORY_CHOICES:
                if a == category:
                    category = b
                    form_post.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/%s' % category)
        else:
            form_post = PostForm()

        context = {
            'allauth_login': allauth_login,
            'allauth_signup': allauth_signup,
            'form_post': form_post
        }

        return render(request, 'post.html', context)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/accounts/signup/")
```

For `initial` -- `These values are only displayed for unbound forms`:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial

Comment: Yeah i'm trying to save post with valid user first, and then redirect to the page to show the new post with user. However your code for some reason doesn't work, the form doesn't submit properly (stays on the same page)